# Execution failed for task: react-native-reanimated:unzipHermes

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-hermes

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':hmscore_react-native-hms-analytics'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':hmscore_react-native-hms-analytics:classpath'.
   > Could not download bundletool-0.13.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.13.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.13.2/bundletool-0.13.2.jar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 19s

    at makeError (/Users/tothenew/Desktop/Work/evod/vrnative/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/tothenew/Desktop/Work/evod/vrnative/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/tothenew/Desktop/Work/evod/vrnative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/tothenew/Desktop/Work/evod/vrnative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
```

I tried removing hermes.tar.gz from **node_modules/react-native/sdks/download/hermes.tar.gz** & executed react-native-run-android again & was able to resolve the issue.